# CSS rollover logo in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, position, rollover

I'm trying to apply a CSS image rollover on a Wordpress header logo. I know this will be a really easy solution for you guys but i can't seem to find the answer anywhere on Stackoverflow. I think it may be to do with position but adding either :relative or :absolute seems to make no difference?

below is my CSS

```
#top {
height: 105px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top:27px;
}
#logo {


/*  background-attachment: scroll;
background-image: url(images/logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;*/
height: 70px;
width: 461px;
 }

 #logo a:hover { 

background-attachment: scroll;
background-image: url('images/flatgrey.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;*/
height: 70px;
width: 461px;


 }

 #logo a {

display:block;
height: 70px;
width: 461px;
```

& PHP

```
  <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="logo">
            <?php               
            ob_start();
            ob_implicit_flush(0);
            echo get_option('imbalance_custom_logo'); 
            $my_logo = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            if (
            $my_logo == ''
            ): ?>
            <a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?    >/images/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
            <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo      get_option('imbalance_custom_logo'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>             
            <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out the *background-attachment* and *background-position* lines for #logo, so the style for #logo was this:

```
#logo {
background-image: url(images/logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 70px;
width: 461px;
 }
```

And that seemed to work for me. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to replace logo.png with flatgrey.png on rollover.  If that is the case, you should get rid of the whole `<img src=".../images/logo.png"...>` tag and then add 
`background-image: url('images/logo.png');` to the CSS of `#logo a`.  You will also want to move the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` line from the CSS of `#logo a:hover` to `#logo a`.